# Ubuntu- really akward

Tags: linux, ubuntu

First of all-

[I have a Samsung mini laptop]

[It has a windows 7 ultimate]

[I am trying to download Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (32-bit)]

[I've downloaded the iso file and copied it to a bootable USB stick]

[I booted ubuntu through it and there was an option to install ubuntu through it]

[I tried to install it but it crashed on the 4th step each and every time]

Now-

I didn't give up and copied wubi(only) from my friend's laptop to my laptop as it's the only thing required to download ubuntu, I downloaded the whole ubuntu from it. Now, when I select the booting option ubuntu, it brings me to a page where I have to enter my username and password. I enter the ones I entered while installing it, but the boot password always fails. (Note*- I haven't tried to boot my laptop from a USB stick, only directly from my laptop.)

Comment: The fourth step, as I recall, was partition selection . For this to be done automatically, you need unallocated disc space and, on an MBR disc, fewer than four existing partitions. Otherwise, you need to configure the partitions manually, but you need to be very careful (note that you do not need a swap _partition_: a swap _file_ is just as effective, except that you won't be able to hibernate). WUBI avoids these restrictions by installing into directories in the existing Windows partition. I can't say why you can't log in: searching for "wubi password" or similar should give you an answer.

Comment: I have no idea why you want Ubuntu (I know why I use it), but you should consider whether installing in a VM will meet your needs.

Comment: FYI, you need a blank line, or two spaces before a CR/newline, to get a newline to show up. And FFYI Wubi hasn't been recommended, or supported, for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't select a partition to install Ubuntu. [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows) will help you.

Make sure you have a separate partition for Ubuntu.